# Error in configuring Flume to Collect Data into HDFS from Twitter - org.apache.commons.cli.UnrecognizedOptionException: Unrecognized option: -conf

Tags: hadoop

Executed the command:

```
./bin/flume-ng agent -conf ./conf/ -f conf/flume.conf -Dflume.root.logger-DEBUG, console -n TwitterAgent
```

and got the following error:

> org.apache.commons.cli.UnrecognizedOptionException: Unrecognized
>   option: -conf

Comment: I did that. Its fine. But Iam getting this log only "2016-10-12 20:50:51,118 (conf-file-poller-0) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:126)] Checking file:conf/flume.conf for changes" continuously.

Answer (score 0):

Change **-conf** to **--conf** , it should work.

The below is the syntax to start Flume.

```
$ bin/flume-ng agent --conf conf --conf-file example.conf --name a1 -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.